# Is there a way to specify min and max values for integer column in slqalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, integer, max, min

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    age = Column(Integer) # I need age to have min value of 0 and max of 100 
    email = Column(String)
```

SQLAlchemy documentation says that there is no such attributes to pass while creating a column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in [brunson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/374642/brunson)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73664202/5320906), you can add a check constraint to perform the validation in the database, if the database supports check constraints.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    age = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.CheckConstraint('age > 0 AND age < 100'))
```

It may be more convenient to perform the validation before data is sent to the database, in the application layer.  In this case, the [orm.validates](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_attributes.html?highlight=validates#simple-validators) decorator can be used:

```py
class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    age = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.CheckConstraint('age > 0 AND age < 100'))

    @orm.validates('age')
    def validate_age(self, key, value):
        if not 0 < value < 100:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid age {value}')
        return value
```

Comment: You forgot to return the `value` from the `validate_age` method. In your example, the age will always be `None`. But nice solution.

Comment: @MiroslavValcicak good spot, thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Model? I am using the model to autogenerate alembic migrations.

Comment: @ajaychawla Not sure what you mean by "in the model"? I _think_ alembic should pick up inline check constraints automtically.

Comment: I am using sqlalchemy declarative_base Class. and creating sub classes out by passing it. i.e. Class User(Base): . So the question is, "Is it possible to code this in my User class and It should be autogenerated by alembic?"

Comment: @ajaychawla is this because you want columns in more than one table to have this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because none of the RDBMSes I'm familiar with support min/max in the column definition.

If you need to enforce that you can write a trigger or if your DB supports it you can add a check constraint.

https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/